# Difference between isomer and isomorph

Tags: graph-theory

In graph theory what is the difference between isomerism and isomorphism? I found a post somewhat similar to it but couldn't understand my problem from that. So I asked again specifically asking my question.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of graph theory, the term isomer does not have a meaning. I do not recall seeing it used. In chemistry, two molecules are isomers if the have same chemical formula, that is the number of atoms of each kind is the same.